# Errors at showing a datepicker and timepicker

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment, timepicker

I have a problem, I have 2 methods to show a TimePicker and a DatePicker. Separately they work well, but If I need to chain one behind other (really I want a one picker with Time and Date, but I've not found a correct way to do it). So, I post the following code.

I'm calling it from a Fragment, when I click a button, but I need that they show one behind other as I said.

```
public void showTimePickerDialog() {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

public void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

public void onFinishTimePickerDialog(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        tmp_hour = hourOfDay;
        tmp_minute = minute;

        String str_day, str_month, str_year, str_hour, str_minute;
        str_year = String.format("%d", tmp_year);
        str_month = String.format("%02d", tmp_month);
        str_day = String.format("%02d", tmp_day);
        str_hour = String.format("%02d", tmp_hour);
        str_minute = String.format("%02d", tmp_minute);

        ((CloseItActivity) getActivity()).setBuydate(str_day + "/" + str_month + "/" + str_year + " " + str_hour + ":" + str_minute);
    }
public void onFinishDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day) {
        tmp_year = year;
        tmp_month = month;
        tmp_day = day;
    }
```

Thank you.

EDIT: If I put showTimePickerDialog() inside of showDatePickerDialog(), the app crashes, I think that It is a context problem, but I don't have it clear.

Log sais that there is a nullexception on onDataSet in the class:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by McFly on 10/05/2014.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    //Interface creada para implementar un método que podamos utilizar como
    //enlace de la actividad en curso y le enviemos la información
    //seleccionada por el usuario.

    public interface DatePickerFragmentListener{
        void onFinishDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Datos que seleccionara el usuario.
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Creamos la instancia del DatePicker para devolverla.
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("LOG_PARENT_FRAG", "" + getParentFragment());
        DatePickerFragmentListener activity = (DatePickerFragmentListener) getParentFragment();
        activity.onFinishDatePickerDialog(year, month, day);

    }
}
```

getParentFragment is null, this is the problem. How I can pass it the context of the parent fragment?

Comment: if they are created dynamically (which is the case) maybe you need to pass the context to create them? (this.context)

Comment: If I put at the end of "onFinishDatePickerDialog(...)" a call to showTimePickerDialog(), the app crashes. You say me that I need to change the context of this for this.context?

Comment: I'm suggesting you send to both showTimePickerDialog(Context context) and showDatePickerDialog(Context context) the context and then you create them with TimePickerFragment(context). It's just a quick suggestion

Comment: It is not a solution because the context of the fragment is the context of the container (context = container.getContext()) that is not the context of the fragment.

Comment: Could you post the error message from LogCat, please?

Comment: I've edited the first post with the DatePickerFragment.